# Color each row based on Clicking the buttons

Tags: excel, vba

I have a bunch of buttons for each row. (Range A1:A200)
I would like to click each individual one, and then he will do the required action (e.g color) the whole row (The range is A:Q).
The way my code is setup at the moment, i would probably need to do the changes on the btn_click function and trigger that.

```
'This creates buttons for the selected range

    Range("A2:A200").Select
    Dim btn As Button
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    ActiveSheet.Buttons.Delete
    Dim t As Range
    ' Find the First & Last Row number of selection
    Dim x As Long, y As Long
    x = Selection.Rows(1).Row
    y = Selection.Rows.Count + x - 1

    For i = x To y ' Loop from first row to last row
       Set t = ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(i, 1), Cells(i, 1))
       Set btn = ActiveSheet.Buttons.Add(t.Left, t.Top, t.Width, t.Height)
       With btn
         .OnAction = "btn_Click"
         .Caption = "LineBreak "
         .Name = "Line Break "
       End With'
    Next i

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

---

```
Sub btn_Click()

    '//CODE NEEDS TO GO IN HERE

End Sub
```

Comment: As a starter read up on how to avoid using select (great post here on SO). Secondly please provide what you have attempted, as I can't see any code trying to set colours. The appropriate  property is `.interior.color = rgb(r, g, b)` or `interior.colorindex = 0`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's quite straightforward with Form buttons:

```
Sub btn_Click()
    Intersect(ActiveSheet.Shapes(Application.Caller).TopLeftCell.EntireRow, Range("A:Q")).Interior.Color = vbRed
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi,

I have added the loop results on the Caption and Name and it worked fine.
Any idea though, instead of inside color, to get Border bottom for example ?

Comment: Replace the `Interior...` part with something like `.borders(xlbottom).weight = xlmedium` for example.

Comment: Ah , so it was borders.
Was using border.
Much appreciated thanks